# Using Selenium and Requests module to get files from webpage in Python3

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm hoping to get some help on an issue I've been having.
I'm fairly new to python and have been working through Al Sweigart's "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" in an effort to simply some very tedious work stuff.

Here's an overview of the issue I'm having:
I'm trying to visit a web page and use the Requests and BeautifulSoup modules to parse through the site, get the URLS to the files I need, and download those files.
The process works great except for one small problem...there is a ReportDropDown option within the page the filters the results shown. The problem I'm having is that, even though the webpage results are updated with the new information, the webpage URL doesn't change and my requests.get() only grabs the information from the default filter.

So, in order to solve that problem, I tried using Selenium to change the report selections...which also works great except that I can't get the Requests module to grab from the Selenium browser instance that I have open.

So it looks like I can use Requests and BeautifulSoup to get the information of the 'default' page drop down filter, and I can use Selenium to change the ReportDropDown options, but I can't combine these two things.

---

Part 1:

```
#! python3
import os, requests, bs4
os.chdir('C:\\Standards')
standardURL = 'http://www.nerc.net/standardsreports/standardssummary.aspx'
res = requests.get(standardURL)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

# this is the url pattern when inspecting the elements on the page
linkElems = soup.select('.style97 a')

# I wanted to save the hyperlinks into a list
splitStandards = []
for link in range(len(linkElems)):
    splitStandards.append(linkElems[link].get('href'))

# Next, I wanted to create the pdf's and copy them locally
print(' STARTING STANDARDS DOWNLOAD '.center(80, '=') + '\n')
for item in splitStandards:
    j = os.path.basename(item)      # BAL-001-2.pdf, etc...
    f = open(j, 'wb')
    ires = requests.get(item)
    # http://www.nerc.com/pa/Stand/Reliability%20Standards/BAL-001-2.pdf
    ires.raise_for_status()
    for chunk in ires.iter_content(1000000):    # 1MB chunks
        f.write(chunk)
    print('Completing download for: ' + str(j) + '.')
    f.close()
print()
print(' STANDARDS DOWNLOAD COMPLETE '.center(80, '='))
```

This pattern works great except that I can't make the ReportDropDown selection change and then use requests to pull the new page info. I've tinkered with requests.get(), requests.post(url, data={}), selenium-requests, etc...

---

Part 2:

Using Selenium seemed straightforward but I couldn't get requests.get() to pull from the correct browser instance. Also, I had to make a Firefox profile (seleniumDefault) that had some aboug:config changes...(windows + r, firefox.exe -p).
Update: The about:config change was to temporarily set browser.tabs.remote.autostart = True

```
from selenium import webdriver

# I used 'fp' to use a specific firefox profile
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\pathto\\Firefox\\Profiles\\seleniumDefault')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
browser.get('http://www.nerc.net/standardsreports/standardssummary.aspx')

# There are 5 possible ReportDropDown selections but I only wanted 3 of them (current, future, inactive).
# In the html code, after a selection is made, it reads as: option selected="selected" value="5" -- where 'value' is the selection number

currentElem = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[0]
futureElem = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[1]
inactiveElem = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[4]

# Using the above code line for "browser.get()" and then currentElem.click(), or futureElem.click(), or inactiveElem.click() correctly changes the page selection. Apparently the browser.get() is needed to refresh the page data before making a new option selection.
# Note: changing the ReportDropDown option doesn't alter the page URL path
```

So, my ultimate question is, how can I make the page selections and pull the appropriate data for each page?

My preference is to use only the requests and bs4 modules for this but if I'm going to use selenium, then how can I get requests to pull from the selenium browser instance I have open?

I've tried to be as thorough as I can be and I'm still fairly new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Plus, since I'm still learning a lot of this, then any novice-intermediate level explanations would rock, thanks!

========================================================

Thanks again for the help, it got me past the wall that was stopping me.
Here's the final product...I had to add some sleep statements for everything to fully load before grabbing the info.

Final Version Revised:

```
#! python3

# _nercTest.py - Opens the nerc.net website and pulls down all
# pdf's for the present, future, and inactive standards.

import os, requests, bs4, time, datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

os.chdir('C:\\Standards')

def nercStandards(standardURL):
    logFile = open('_logFile.txt', 'w')
    logFile.write('Standard\t\tHyperlinks or Errors\t\t' +
                  str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")) + '\n\n')
    logFile.close()
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\pathto\\Firefox\\Profiles\\seleniumDefault')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    currentOption = 'Mandatory Standards Subject to Enforcement'
    futureOption = 'Standards Subject to Future Enforcement'
    inactiveOption = 'Inactive Reliability Standards'

    dropdownList = [currentOption, futureOption, inactiveOption]

    print()
    print(' STARTING STANDARDS DOWNLOAD '.center(80, '=') + '\n')
    for option in dropdownList:
        standardName = []   # Capture all the standard names accurately
        standardLink = []   # Capture all the href links for each standard
        standardDict = {}   # combine the standardName and standardLink into a dictionary 
        browser.get(standardURL)
        dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ReportDropDown"))
        dropdown.select_by_visible_text(option)
        wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > span[class="style12"]'), option))

        time.sleep(3)   # Needed for the 'inactive' page to completely load consistently
        page_source = browser.page_source
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
        soupElems = soup.select('.style97 a')

        # standardLink list generated here
        for link in range(len(soupElems)):
            standardLink.append(soupElems[link].get('href'))
            # http://www.nerc.com/pa/Stand/Reliability%20Standards/BAL-001-2.pdf

        # standardName list generated here
        if option == currentOption:
            print(' Mandatory Standards Subject to Enforcement '.center(80, '.') + '\n')
            currentElems = soup.select('.style99 span[class="style30"]')
            for currentStandard in range(len(currentElems)):
                   standardName.append(currentElems[currentStandard].getText())
                   # BAL-001-2
        elif option == futureOption:
            print()
            print(' Standards Subject to Future Enforcement '.center(80, '.') + '\n')
            futureElems = soup.select('.style99 span[class="style30"]')
            for futureStandard in range(len(futureElems)):
                   standardName.append(futureElems[futureStandard].getText())
                   # COM-001-3       
        elif option == inactiveOption:
            print()
            print(' Inactive Reliability Standards '.center(80, '.') + '\n')
            inactiveElems = soup.select('.style104 font[face="Verdana"]')
            for inactiveStandard in range(len(inactiveElems)):
                   standardName.append(inactiveElems[inactiveStandard].getText())
                   # BAL-001-0

        # if nunber of names and links match, then create key:value pairs in standardDict
        if len(standardName) == len(standardLink):
            for x in range(len(standardName)):
                standardDict[standardName[x]] = standardLink[x]
        else:
            print('Error: items in standardName and standardLink are not equal!')
            logFile = open('_logFile.txt', 'a')
            logFile.write('\nError: items in standardName and standardLink are not equal!\n')
            logFile.close()

        # URL correction for PRC-005-1b
        # if 'PRC-005-1b' in standardDict:
        #     standardDict['PRC-005-1b'] = 'http://www.nerc.com/files/PRC-005-1.1b.pdf'

        for k, v in standardDict.items():
            logFile = open('_logFile.txt', 'a')
            f = open(k + '.pdf', 'wb')
            ires = requests.get(v)
            try:
                ires.raise_for_status()
                logFile.write(k + '\t\t' + v + '\n')
            except Exception as exc:
                print('\nThere was a problem on %s: \n%s' % (k, exc))
                logFile.write('There was a problem on %s: \n%s\n' % (k, exc))
            for chunk in ires.iter_content(1000000):
                    f.write(chunk)
            f.close()
            logFile.close()
            print(k + ': \n\t' + v)
    print()
    print(' STANDARDS DOWNLOAD COMPLETE '.center(80, '='))

nercStandards('http://www.nerc.net/standardsreports/standardssummary.aspx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've done the work with Selenium clicking buttons etc you need to tell BeautifulSoup to use it:

```
    page_source = browser.page_source
    link_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! 
I had tried something similar to this and it didn't run quite right. However, when I use this in IDLE then it runs correctly. When I use this as my nercTest.py, then it still only captures the default standards. 
I suspect it has to do with the loading of the page. Is there a way to make sure that the page selection from the ".click()" has completed loading prior to the page_source = browser.page_source storing the data? 

Perhaps if I spit them into two separate functions? 

def browserSelection():

def selectStandards():

Answer (score 1):

@HenryM is on the right track, except that before you read the `.page_source` and pass it to `BeautifulSoup` for further parsing, you need to make sure that your desired data is there loaded. For this, use a [`WebDriverWait` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

For example, after you select the, say, "Standards Filed and Pending Regulatory Approval" option, you need to wait for the report title to be updated - this would be an indication for you that the new results were loaded. Something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# ...

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

option_text = "Standards Filed and Pending Regulatory Approval" 

# select the dropdown value
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ReportDropDown"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text(option_text)

# wait for results to be loaded
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#panel5 > div > span"), option_text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
# TODO: parse the results
```

Also note the use of [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) to manipulate the dropdown.

Comment: alecxe, I just saw this. I'll tinker with it in a bit and see what I can learn.
Thanks for the assist!